# Deleting a row from a table using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to add a button which allows the user to remove a row of data for the database in laravel 5.2 application. This however is producing this error:

> FatalErrorException in PageController.php line 53:
>   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Event' not found

I am not sure why this happens. Below is the code I have used to try and implement the method.

Page controller:

```
public function delete_event($id)
{   $event=Event::findOrFail($id);

    $event->delete();
    return redirect('events');
}
 This is where I populate the table and create the buttons:

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'delete_event']) !!}

        <div class="form-group">

            <?php
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                echo "<tr><td>{$row->name}</td><td>{$row->description}</td><td>{$row->datetime}</td><td>{$row->location}</td><td><a href='/delete_event/{{$row->id}}'  class='btn btn-success btn-danger'></a></td></tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/delete_event/{id}', 'PageController@delete_event');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your model in your controller:

```
use App\Event;
```

Add that to the top above the class definition.

Comment: I have the model in but the delete still isn't functioning.@AngadDubey

Comment: @Hannah The error you get `FatalErrorException in PageController.php line 53: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Event' not found` is because the `Event` model is not being imported. Has the error changed?

Comment: It has actually it's now "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:"

Comment: That exception is thrown when you acces a route via a method (get/post) that you haven't setup. Like when you setup getIndex and send a post request to that index (needing postIndex or anyIndex, which is missing). It's unrelated to this question, @AngadDubey should get this answer as accepted.